# Best way to set multiple global variables in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I have 20 + global variables and 10+ associative array in one js file, and also I have some functions to calculate and to display. And I need to store those vlaues in localstorage. Do we have any best way to store the variables, arrays and functions?
EX:

```
var country=region=detailOne=detailTwo='';
var websiteOne=webSitetwo=0;
var channel=[];

var RateCard={
                India:{a:0,b:0,c:0},
                Australia:{a:0,b:0,c:0}
               }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a bunch of vars, use a single object:

```
var myData = {
   country: ...,
   region: ....
   etc
```

and then simply:

```
 localStorage.myData = JSON.stringify(myData);
```

However, you cannot store *functions* this way - why would you want to, anyways?

Comment: perhaps he can store functions also. by adding functions as properties of this object.